# Change IP settings using C++

Tags: c++, network-programming, windows-ce, ip-address

How do I change the IP settings of a Windows CE 6 box Programatically via C++? Functions for Windows might also work.

I found that I can change the hostname via [sethostname](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee493673.aspx) but couldn't find how to change IP address settings such as:

- IP Address
- DHCP
- Subnet
- Gateway
- DNS1 / DNS2
- WINS1 / WINS2

Any advice / pointers would be great.
Thanks.

P.s. How would you get the box to update to those settings - is a refresh or the programming equivalent of `ipconfig /renew` required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked out the [IP Helper Routines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa923597.aspx) on MSDN?  I think these provide some, if not all, of what you need.

**EDIT: ** Updated link. Thanks ctacke

Comment: The link for the CE versions is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa923597.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Most of these fall under the IpHlp API.

You don't really *change* an IP address -- you use [`DeleteIpAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365875%28VS.85%29.aspx) delete the old one, then [`AddIpAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365801%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to add the new one. You specify the subnet mask when you add an address.

It's not clearly what you want to know about DHCP. You can use DHCP via [`IpReleaseAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366056%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [`IpRenewAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366057%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). You can get the address of the current DHCP server with [`GetAdaptersInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365917%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (among others). At least if memory serves, getting its address is mostly for information though -- since the basic idea of DHCP is to avoid manual configuration, you normally find/use it via a broadcast message.

<strike>You can set the DNS and WINS servers via the the WMI [`Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394217%28VS.85%29.aspx) class (`SetDNSServerSearchOrder` and `SetWinsServer`)</strike>

You can adjust quite a few (most?) of the other parameters via WMI as well.

Comment: WMI isn't available for WinCE.

Comment: @ctacke: Oops -- in the process of writing the reply, I forgot the minor detail about its being for CE. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: using IpHelper, AddIpAddress, does NOT change the ip address persistently.
After a reboot, the original NIC settings are back.